# JavaScript Resize Font

Tags: javascript, font-size

```
var ref = document.getElementById("ref");
var bio = document.getElementById("bio");
var size = 0.1;
bio.style.fontSize = "0.1vw";
while(ref.style.height < bio.style.height) {
    size += 0.1;
    bio.style.fontSize = concat(toString(size), 'vw');
}
```

Hi,
I'm trying to get this script to work so that the font-size of div "bio" makes its height equal to or just larger than the height of a div next to it, "ref". The code above does not work. Can you help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use fontSize instead of font-size. That's how the Javascript properties are written.
Like this:

```
bio.style.fontSize = ...
```

And any other styling that would normally have a dash in css is camelCase in Javascript